# T-SQL brackets single quote and sql injection

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-injection

consider:

```
CString username="john['dow";
CString password="mypass";
ExecSQL("CREATE LOGIN ["+username+"] WITH PASSWORD = '"+password+"', CHECK_POLICY = OFF, DEFAULT_DATABASE = Voyager, CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF"));
```

(where ExecSQL executes the SQL on an SQL server DB)

Using brackets for username as it may contain a dot

I have a check that password does not contain a single quote (but I understand it can safely contain any other char ?)

I have a check that username does not contain a closing bracket.

Is there any other chars that is unsafe for username ? in particular is open brackets or single quote unsafe for username in this case ?

Thanks

Comment: don't concatentate strings. use parameters

Comment: can that be done without stored procedure for CREATE LOGIN ? how ?

Comment: The *safest* way to do this would be to not be thinking about escaping at all. But since we cannot parameterize `CREATE LOGIN`, that seems to be a dead end. Or is it? What language is this current (outer) code in? Does it have a means of binding to .NET assemblies? If so, [SQL Management Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.login.aspx) would seem to be the way to go here.

Comment: Please note it's a duplicate of your previous question that's also a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

Go over this article and it will give you the best practices for username and password:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments

**Login_name**
Specifies the name of the login that is created. There are four types of logins: SQL Server logins, Windows logins, certificate-mapped logins, and asymmetric key-mapped logins. When you are creating logins that are mapped from a Windows domain account, you must use the pre-Windows 2000 user logon name in the format [\]. You cannot use a UPN in the format login_name@DomainName. For an example, see example D later in this topic. SQL Server authentication logins are type sysname and must conform to the rules for [Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-2017) and cannot contain a '\'. Windows logins can contain a '\'. Logins based on Active Directory users, are limited to names of less than 21 characters.

**PASSWORD ='password'**
Applies to SQL Server logins only. Specifies the password for the login that is being created. You should use a strong password. For more information see Strong Passwords and Password Policy. Beginning with SQL Server 2012 (11.x), stored password information is calculated using SHA-512 of the salted password.

Passwords are case-sensitive. Passwords should always be at least 8 characters long, and cannot exceed 128 characters. Passwords can include a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and most non-alphanumeric characters. Passwords cannot contain single quotes, or the login_name.

**PASSWORD =hashed_password**
Applies to: SQL Server 2008 through SQL Server 2017.

Applies to the HASHED keyword only. Specifies the hashed value of the password for the login that is being created.

Comment: Thank you Deepak, as far as I understand on windows servers the windows password complexity policy applies when creating SQL server passwords ?

Comment: I cannot comment on that as I am completely unaware of the complexity requirement for creating Windows account password but if it is the same as described above, then yes. Hope it helps. If it answers your original question, please mark it as an answer.